# Row-wise DataFrame segmentation

Tags: python, pandas, boolean-expression

Given the following dataframe:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(data={'item': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'start':[0.0, 2.0, 8.0, 6.0], 
                            'end': [2.0, 6.0, 8.0, 14.0]})
```

How do I quickly expand the above dataframe row-wise by segmenting the interval 'start' - 'end' into multiples of 2?

For the above example, the resulting dataframe should be

```
    Out=
       item  start   end    
       1     0.0     2.0
       2     2.0     4.0
       2     4.0     6.0
       3     8.0     8.0
       4     6.0     8.0  
       4     8.0     10.0  
       4     10.0    12.0  
       4     12.0    14.0
```

Performance is of utmost importance for me, as I have millions of lines to check. 
I had already filtered the entire dataframe using boolean indexing for those rows that do not need segmenting. That is a great speed-up However, on the remainder of the rows I applied a 'for loop' and made dataframes of the correct length that I kept appending. Unfortunately, the performance is not sufficient for millions of rows.

Looking forward to expert solutions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from the original dataframe:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    df = pd.DataFrame(data={'item': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'start':[0.0, 2.0, 8.0, 6.0], 
                            'end': [2.0, 6.0, 10.0, 14.0]})
```

Then, run the following code:

```
    lengths = pd.Series([1, 2, 1, 4]) #  For the example, I just created this array, 
                                      #  but obviously I would use the mod function to 
                                      #  determine the number of segments to create

    # Row below elongates the dataframe according to the array 'lengths'

    df = df.reindex(np.repeat(df.index.values, lengths), method='ffill')
    df['start'] += pd.Series(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()*2.0)
    df['end'] = df['start'] + 2.0
    print df
```

Note that the initial dataframe contained an error. Item '3' required a 'start=8.0' and 'end=10.0'.

I believe this method is extremely quick due to the use of pandas Cython functions. Of course, still open to other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that returns a DataFrame of the expanded start and end times. In this example, I groupby `item` as I'm not sure you can return a DataFrame from `apply` without it being grouped first.

```
def convert(row):
    start = row.start.values[0]
    end = row.end.values[0]
    if start == end:
        return pd.DataFrame([[start, end]], columns=['start', 'end'])
    else:
        return pd.DataFrame({'start': np.arange(start, end, 2),
                            'end':np.arange(start + 2, end + 2, 2)},
                           columns=['start', 'end'])

df1=df.groupby('item').apply(convert)
df1.index = df1.index.droplevel(1)
df1.reset_index()

    item  start   end
0     1    0.0   2.0
1     2    2.0   4.0
2     2    4.0   6.0
3     3    8.0   8.0
4     4    6.0   8.0
5     4    8.0  10.0
6     4   10.0  12.0
7     4   12.0  14.0
```

Comment: Thank you. I had done something similar previously. I posted an alternative solution that I believe is much quicker.